# Mysql ORDER BY conditions in query depends on date

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sql-order-by, conditional-statements, case

I have one mysql query, which gets rows to designs list. In this list we have "normal" rows, which are sorted by their id, and "special" rows which are sorted by "special_end" (this is date, in all rows it's NULL now) parameter. So, "special" rows in result should be higher than "normal".

Query now:

```
SELECT d.*, DATE_FORMAT(_created, '%d.%m.%Y') as _created_human, count(dp.id) photos_cnt, u.id user_id, u.class_name user_class_name, u.full_name user_full_name
FROM designs d
LEFT JOIN design_photo dp ON d.id=dp.design_id 
LEFT JOIN cms_user u ON d.cms_user_id=u.id
WHERE 1=1  AND d.status_id=1 AND d.published=1 AND u.cms_user_status_id=1 
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY d.special_end DESC, id DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

I need to upgrade ORDER BY block in this query to sort rows with special_end parameter with condition:

- if d.special_end >= DATE( NOW() ) -> sort by d.special_end DESC,
- if d.special_end <= DATE( NOW() ) -> sort by id DESC.

Example (id -  row - special_end):

```
515 design4 2012-07-21
514 design3 2012-06-30
526 design5 null
513 design2 2012-05-30 (this date is <= DATE( NOW() ))
512 design1 null
511 design0 null
.
.
.
```

I've already try to write something like

```
ORDER BY CASE d.special_end WHEN d.special_end >= DATE( NOW() ) THEN d.special_end WHEN d.special_end <= DATE( NOW() ) THEN d.id END DESC
```

or

```
ORDER BY IF(d.special_end >= DATE( NOW() ), d.special_end, d.id) DESC
```

but no result.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordering by a condition might be terribly slow, I'd rather use `UNION` to achieve the same result:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
    (
        SELECT d.*, DATE_FORMAT(_created, '%d.%m.%Y') as _created_human, count(dp.id) photos_cnt, u.id user_id, u.class_name user_class_name, u.full_name user_full_name
        FROM designs d
        LEFT JOIN design_photo dp ON d.id=dp.design_id 
        LEFT JOIN cms_user u ON d.cms_user_id=u.id
        WHERE d.special_end >= DATE(NOW()) AND d.status_id=1 AND d.published=1 AND u.cms_user_status_id=1 
        GROUP BY d.id
        ORDER BY d.special_end DESC
    ) UNION (
        SELECT d.*, DATE_FORMAT(_created, '%d.%m.%Y') as _created_human, count(dp.id) photos_cnt, u.id user_id, u.class_name user_class_name, u.full_name user_full_name
        FROM designs d
        LEFT JOIN design_photo dp ON d.id=dp.design_id 
        LEFT JOIN cms_user u ON d.cms_user_id=u.id
        WHERE (d.special_end < DATE(NOW()) OR d.special_end IS NULL) AND d.status_id=1 AND d.published=1 AND u.cms_user_status_id=1 
        GROUP BY d.id
        ORDER BY d.id DESC
    )
) t LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. There should be one extre ")" before LIMIT (otherwise - Syntax error message). And now i get " Every derived table must have its own alias" message.

Comment: It might, just might, work with `UNION ALL`. I wouldn't trust `UNION` for this.

Comment: @VasiliyToporov oh, I apologize, fixed. 
@ypercube `UNION ALL` could be used too, but why don't you trust `UNION`?

Comment: After editing there is "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY" message. And before edeting I've got interesting result: d.special_end  DESC block works correctly, and d.id DESC block (with outdated designs) is sorted by d.id ASC.

Comment: @VasiliyToporov again, sorry. MySQL has really stupid syntax rules, I had to put parentheses back to query. The incorrect sorting you reported doesn't make sense, since my query had a typo :) this version should be OK.

Comment: @DragonJake I've also add WHERE (d.special_end < DATE(NOW()) OR d.special_end IS NULL). In other case query just give only "special" rows because d.special_end is a new parameter. Also, the "normal" rows is sorted by id ASC. So  ORDER BY d.id DESC do not work. I can delete it and result would be the same.

Comment: @VasiliyToporov Did the query returned 20 rows as specified by `LIMIT` or less? Because I don't know the data you're selecting with this query, so try `UNION ALL` suggested by @ypercube instead.

Answer (score 2):

Always split your query with UNION when ever there is multiple Group by or sorting requirement.
Just split your query with an UNION operater and do sorting.like below

```
Select * from Something where <condtion> order by 1 desc
UNION
Select * from Something where <condtion> order by 2 desc
```